# Flutter number only TextField inside FutureBuilder can't type first time

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, keyboard, future

I have a Flutter application for listing products. I'm trying to test it on Android.
I have number (keyboard type number) only `TextField` inside `FutureBuilder`. But when I click on textfield keyboard appears but I can't type. when I click again in `TextField` typing is ok. This problem happens only if `keyboardType` is set to numbers. Only after taping twice able to type into `TextField`.

Tried, `autoFocus`, `focusNode` etc but no luck.

Comment: Did you ever work this out? Facing the same issue.